# How to traverse JSON object using a key like method name { "GROUP(date)": "2019-09"} - ballerina

Tags: json, ballerina

I have a json object like following

```
"values": {
      "GROUP(date)": "2019-09",
      "GROUP(account)": [
            {
                 "value": "228",
                 "text": "Subscription"
             }
         ],
       "SUM(amount)": "630.638",
}
```

The json object consists of key value pairs like above snippet.
But the key is like method name coz there is a bracket like `GROUP(date)`.

when I try to traverse using the key it not recognize the key.
`values.GROUP(date)`

what is the way to get the value using this kind of key in ballerina?

Answer (score 3):

To use field access like `values.GROUP(date)`, the parentheses can be escaped.

```
values.GROUP\(date\)
```

Alternatively, if the static type of `values` is a map (e.g., `map<json>` which represents JSON objects), member access can be used with a string literal.

```
values["GROUP(date)"]
```

Comment: I preferred second solution since there are multiple layers to traverse including arrays. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer that I found.

```
"values": {
      "GROUP(date)": "2019-09",
      "GROUP(account)": [
            {
                 "value": "228",
                 "text": "Subscription"
             }
         ],
       "SUM(amount)": "630.638",
}
```

```
         // direct call by key
         string date = values["GROUP(date)"].toString();
        
         // access value inside the array
         json[] account = <json[]> values["GROUP(account)"];
         map<json> account_obj = <map<json>> account[0];
         string account_value = check account_obj.text;
```

I tries to define a record and access the object. But wasn't able to have the approach.